# How to add an event listener to a solid line between two coordinates

Tags: java, android, eclipse, graphics

I want to let the user create straight lines ( with the onTouch handler) where each line is connected with the previous line.
When the user is done with drawing these connected straight lines I want to give the user the possibility to add a name to each line.

The first part, connecting straight lines with each other, is probably not the most difficult part. With onTouch and a View/Paint object I can probably fix this job.
However, the difficult part is how to add the text to a particular straight line? Maybe an eventListener could indicate that the user pressed on the line (onTouchListener) and subsequently come up with a function to add the text? 
However, as far as I know, I cannot add an onTouchListener to a painted line.
Thus, what is the right direction? Maybe I can place each written line in a separate View object?

Answer (score 0):

Solution A (if the user draws one line for every one click):

Create a Button outside/over the canvas, that the user can press when he/she is done with the drawing and wants to start labeling.
This way your canvas will have two possible states: Drawing/Labeling. Your onTouch method will consider this to whether draw a line (what you do now), or to find the closest line and label it.
Finding the target line to label, requires you to keep a data structure that contains all the lines the user has drawn. A simple (not the better) approach can be a LinkedList. When the user clicks the screen and your current canvas state is 'Labeling', you iterate the list and, for each Line, you calculate the distance between the onTouch event point (getRawX, getRawY) and the line [Distance between a point and a line@Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line).
In the end you label the closest line (by popping a dialog or something like that).

Solution B (if the user draws a line with a drag gesture)
You don't need the button, nor the Canvas state. Just detect the single-click (the down and up touch events occur in the same coordinates). The data structure/algorithm from Solution A still apply.

Comment: Thank you very much for these solutions. Maybe I could even skip the state button you suggest, by introducing a particular maximum distance, When the distance from onTouch event point to the line is smaller than the maximum the App directly gives the user the possibility to add the label.
I also need to keep a list that contains all the connection points between one line and another, because I want to enforce that only from these connection points a new line can be drawn.